# Bitbucket Pipeline Java (Gradle) not found errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to building pipelines.  Below is a Screenshot of the failed pipeline, does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

**SOLUTION**

The gradlew file was produced with hyphenation in-front of each line which is incorrect, removing them via notepad++ replaceAll feature fixed the format of the file and the pipeline fired successfully.

Comment: what guide are you following for BitBucket Pipelines?

Comment: I was following this guide https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/java-with-bitbucket-pipelines-872013773.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The gradlew file was produced with hyphenation in-front of each line which is incorrect, removing them via notepad++ replaceAll feature fixed the format of the file and the pipeline fired successfully.